# Successful UEFI secure boot exploitation

Tags: malware, rootkits, uefi, secure-boot

Are there any real examples (malware, rootkits, etc.) of exploiting the UEFI secure boot mechanism vulnerabilities such as [CVE-2022-21894](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2022-21894)?

Comment: CVE-2022-21894 is **not** a secure boot vulnerability. It is a Windows bootloader vulnerability that allows bypassing security boot.

Answer (score 1):

Just recently [BlackLotus UEFI bootkit](https://www.welivesecurity.com/2023/03/01/blacklotus-uefi-bootkit-myth-confirmed/) has been discovered which not only exploits this vulnerability, it does a ton more to gain persistence (complete system reinstallation will *not* help - you'll have to reset MOK keys and probably even reflash BIOS) it disables multiple Windows 11 protections to remain completely undetected.